# Problema com o comando TextToColumns

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Estou fazendo a leitura de um arquivo txt no excel via VBA. Consigo ler sem problemas, mas como as linhas tem tamanhos fixos diferentes, a depender da informação que ela possui eu preciso fazer uma tabulação diferente para cada uma, porém o comando *TextToColumns* não retorna nada.

Um exemplo abaixo do que estou fazendo para a celula A1

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Workbooks.OpenText Filename:= _
        "\\cifs-zone3\transfarq\SATE\djo\2024\01 - Janeiro\djo190.001.2024010200016982.111.BB", StartRow _
        :=7, DataType:=xlDelimited, Other:=True, OtherChar:="@"

Range("A1").TextToColumns DataType:=xlFixedWidth, TrailingMinusNumbers:=True, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 2), Array(26, 2), Array(51, 2), Array(76, 2), _
        Array(101, 2), Array(105, 2), Array(135, 2), Array(149, 2), Array(179, 2), Array(193, 2))

End Sub
```

Comment: Eu também já fiz diversas importações via VBA. Após conhecer os recursos do Power Query, essa importação ficou mais fácil e robusta. Te aconselho a aprofundar nisto, pois verá que seu esforço valerá a pena. Lidar com essas diferenças de tamanho de texto, por exemplo, é bem mais fácil com o Power Query